# Show Submenu using only CSS and JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I place this here because I hit a wall, I am trying to show a submenu and hide the parent, something like this

[image: Menu]

Where when clicking in Who We Are, should show me the submenu

[image: Sub-Menu]

like the mockups in the images

**IMPORTANT**: It's only for the menu on desktop, mobile mockups are for reference. And At All Cost avoid jQuery

I am using vanilla JavaScript and CSS3, but I have no way to do it, this is what I have done:

```
// Desktop Menu
var desktopMenues = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children');
var desktopSubMenues = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children .menu-item-has-children');

[].forEach.call(desktopSubMenues, function(desktopSubMenu) {
  
  desktopSubMenu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var parent    = desktopSubMenu.parentNode;
    var children  = desktopSubMenu.children[1];
    console.log(parent);
    console.log(children);
    console.log('FLAG');
  });

});
```

I tried modifying using, z-index, visibility, display, etc, without success, so the question here, would be how do I show the submenu as the mockups suggest?

Here is the Dev URL:

https://cjapdvdev.wpengine.com/

Comment: You mean the mobile menus right? The mockups you've posted are for mobile

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui the mobile mockup is an example, I need it for the Desktop Menu

Answer (score 0):

Try The following. Hope this example helps

```
<div class="background"></div>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation no-padding" role="navigation">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-home">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
            <a href="#">Who We Are</a>          
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Stores One</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Stores Two</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Stores Three</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Stores Four</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>                
</nav>  



*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}

.background{
    background-position:center !important;
    height: 100vh;background-color: #ccc;
}

.main-navigation {  
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    clear: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;  
    left: 100px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; 
    width: 300px;  
    z-index: 10;
}

.main-navigation ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0;
}

.main-navigation li{
    list-style:none;
    position: static;
}

.main-navigation .span-wrap{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation li a{
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding:10px 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation li a:hover{
    color:#000000;
}

.dropdown {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block !important;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 15;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.dropdown.right{
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown.left{
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
}

.main-navigation .sub-menu {
    box-shadow: none;
    bottom: 0;
    display:none;
    left: 300px;
    padding-left: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 10;   
}

.main-navigation .menu{
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.main-navigation.open .menu{
    left: -300px;
}



jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
      jQuery('<span class="dropdown right">click<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>').insertAfter('.menu-item-has-children > a');
  
      jQuery('<span class="dropdown left">click<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>').prependTo('.sub-menu');
  
      jQuery('.main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children').each(function(){
          jQuery(this).children('a, span').wrapAll('<span class="span-wrap"></span>')
      });
  
  
        jQuery('.dropdown.right').on("click", function(){ 
            jQuery(this).parent().next('.sub-menu').show();
            jQuery('#site-navigation').addClass('open');
        }); 
  
        jQuery('.sub-menu').find('.dropdown.left').on("click", function(){ 
            jQuery(this).parent().hide();
            jQuery('#site-navigation').removeClass('open');
        }); 
   
      
});
```